# How to get collection from Shopify SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shopify

I am Work With `Shopify SDK`. I Succesfully integrated it but the problem is when I have try to get collection from shopify then my app is crashed?

I have follow [this](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios) tutorial which provided by shopify.

**Code**

```
// Shopify Initializtion


BUYClient *client;

client = [[BUYClient alloc] initWithShopDomain:SHOP_DOMAIN
                                                   apiKey:API_KEY
                                                    appId:APP_ID];

[client getCollectionsPage:1 completion:^(NSArray<BUYCollection *> *  collections, NSUInteger page, BOOL reachedEnd, NSError *error)
{

    // here get a collection

}];
```

**Crash**

[image]

Please help me to short out this.

Comment: Hi now I started to develope an app with Shopify. I need advice. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Good news for you is I solved this earlier this week! You are probably using their static framework which has some issues presently (I think they will update their docs to reflect this).

Here was the answer I wrote on their GitHub issues board:

> This stack-overflow answer ended up being the solution:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/29453132 I had to take the "Mobile Buy
>   SDK.xcdatamodel" from the Mobile Buy SDK project, and put it into my
>   project (plus make sure it is in compile sources!). After this, my
>   project works with the static framework.

Comment: Do you know how to convert string to buy product array